# How do I debug EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL) error report?

Tags: ios, swift

We recently got a crash report from a user and currently are investigating it.

As far as I know this type of error means that app was taking too long to launch but I can't understand why exactly is it happening. Maybe anyone has any ideas?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: FRONTBOARD 2343432205 
<RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:[application<bundle_id>:395] failed to terminate gracefully after 5.0s
ProcessVisibility: Unknown
ProcessState: Running
WatchdogEvent: process-exit
WatchdogVisibility: Background
WatchdogCPUStatistics: (
"Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 7.120 (user 5.670, system 1.450), 19% CPU",
"Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.000, 0% CPU"
) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>

Triggered by Thread:  0

Kernel Triage:
VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage


Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f4f4a358 kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1bd728e20 _dispatch_kq_poll + 172
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1bd7289d8 _dispatch_kq_drain + 256
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1bd728338 _dispatch_event_loop_poke + 156
4   AXCoreUtilities                        0x1c13bf7ec AXPerformBlockOnMainThreadAfterDelay + 120
5   AccessibilityUtilities                 0x1bf7761dc _axmonitor_dyld_image_callback + 236
6   dyld                                   0x1d5738aec invocation function for block in dyld4::APIs::_dyld_register_func_for_add_image(void (*)(mach_header const*, long)) + 200
7   dyld                                   0x1d5732e84 dyld4::RuntimeState::withLoadersReadLock(void () block_pointer) + 92
8   dyld                                   0x1d576fefc dyld4::APIs::_dyld_register_func_for_add_image(void (*)(mach_header const*, long)) + 160
9   AccessibilityUtilities                 0x1bf7ebc4c __23-[AXBinaryMonitor init]_block_invoke + 52
10  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1bd704320 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1bd705eac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1bd7146a4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1bd7142f4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
14  CoreFoundation                         0x1b62d5d18 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
15  CoreFoundation                         0x1b62b7650 __CFRunLoopRun + 1992
16  CoreFoundation                         0x1b62bc4dc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
17  GraphicsServices                       0x1f151c35c GSEventRunModal + 164
18  UIKitCore                              0x1b864837c -[UIApplication _run] + 888
19  UIKitCore                              0x1b8647fe0 UIApplicationMain + 340
20  libswiftUIKit.dylib                    0x1becc20b0 UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 104
21  AppName                                0x10098b0cc 0x100984000 + 28876
22  dyld                                   0x1d5744dec start + 2220
```

Comment: check your system connection with device, chances that your device is frequently getting disconnected!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the [watchdog terminations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-watchdog-terminations):

> The watchdog terminates apps that block the main thread for a significant time.

It also tells you the reason right there:

> failed to terminate gracefully after 5.0s

as well tells you this:

> WatchdogVisibility: Background

I have never found the proper docs for this message, but from the experience, I think they happen when app is coming from background.

So basically my interpretation of this crash would be:

- happens when the app is coming from background, but hangs
- iOS tells it to terminate (maybe user chose force close), but app still didn't terminate gracefully, so watchdog killed it

So IMO your effort should be towards understanding what do you do when the app comes to foreground, or what you don't do right when the app goes to background. You are looking for something that is happening on main thread, blocking it. It's also possible that app was already hung when user put it on background, so the issue may be even earlier.

Check especially network calls, open DB connections, Vision requests, etc - anything that is not supposed to be on main thread, and can take a long time.